# C# float and double bug

Tags: c#

I have this code:

```
static void Main()
{
    float i;

    for (i = 0; i <= 100; i = i + 0.01F)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(i);

    }

}
```

And it prints me this:

```
0
0.01
0.02
0.03
0.04
0.05
0.05999999
0.06999999
0.07999999
0.08999999
0.09999999
0.11
```

Is this a bug or am I doing something wrong?
Is there any solution to this?

Comment: http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/General/FloatingPoint.aspx

Comment: [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html)

Comment: There are numerous duplicates on [SO] that explain the behavior of floating point values in C# and other languages, I picked one of them that I thought explained the problem nicely, if you require other explanations/examples, please do a search for [float bug .NET](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=float+bug+%5B.net%5D)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is not a bug. This is a fundamental property of floating point numbers. The numbers are stored as a mantissa and an exponent and they cannot represent every number possible with perfect precision. If you need precision, you have to use decimal types.

For a lot of information about this see [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html)

Comment: It's not a bug, it's a feature. :)

Comment: Thank you, decimal does the trick for me.