# C# rounding of double not working

Tags: c#, math, rounding

I have this code to round some value. I am using Math.Round() for the same.

`double h = 128.015999031067;
 double d = Math.Round(h, 3) * 1000;`

result is `128015.99999999999`
if I write it to console it gives me `128016`. I want the value to be `128016`

Am I missing any type conversions? Or there is some other way of doing this?

Comment: But it is working as you expected - https://dotnetfiddle.net/szBxpQ - the output is `128016`

Comment: Very carefully consider your numerics here, IEEE 754 `float` and `double` cannot accurately represent all numbers. Verify that these types will work correctly for the calculations you wish to make.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24859628/c-sharp-float-and-double-bug/24859646#24859646

Comment: @FelipeOriani let me know if it prints Match  https://dotnetfiddle.net/kQB4Xk

Comment: You can consider using `decimal` https://dotnetfiddle.net/FCcepy

Comment: @FelipeOriani I know that's one solutions. Just trying to avoid type conversion changes in my code. Thanks

Answer (score 8):

`128.016` cannot be represented exactly in binary. There is no way that you will get `128016` by multiplying with `1000`.

There are multiple ways around this:

- Do nothing. It is already printed correctly. (Unless you want to perform further calculations.)
- The "obvious" solution would be to simply round *again*.
- The "simplest" solution would be to multiply first, then round.
- The most "correct" solution would be, if you need exact values, you should use an exact type; there are many implementations of bignum, rational, decimal, and precise arithmetic available via NuGet, also consider using `decimal`.

Comment: I want to perform a value match of the rounded value which it fails. And I am rounding it again as u mentioned. I cannot round first as the values will be different. Its a general implementation which works for all other values except this one.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the round function without any other arguments?

`double h = 128.015999031067;
double d = Math.Round(h*1000);`